# Touchpad and mouse do not work in live boot - advised to use "nomodeset" but don't know how to do so

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, live-usb

I was trying to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS alongside Windows 10 on my laptop.

I got the USB and followed the video and everything worked up to where I clicked **Try Ubuntu without installing** and when the desktop loaded I was not able to use my touchpad. A wireless mouse worked but I was not able to click.

Someone told me

> You need to boot the installation media with an additional boot parameter `nomodeset` and also when booting the installed system until you install the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

I have no clue what the user means by any of this as I am very new to Ubuntu, can someone explain how to do these things and what it means? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### Booting with nomodeset

When booting press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get out of language, Hit the <kbd>F6</kbd> key, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> again. Now after `---` type a space and `nomodeset` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After installation, under **System Settings**, double-click **Additional Drivers** and Nvidia should be listed, try the latest one first.